# Changing chart size in VBA when exporting to power point

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint

I am trying to make the exported charts larger on the powerpoint slide, but keep running into issues with the loop. Any ideas?

```
Sub Export_Worksheet()

    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim SldIndex As Integer

    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True

    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    SldIndex = 1

    For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

        Chrt.Copy
    
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
            PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste

        SldIndex = SldIndex + 1
        
    Next Chrt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code. It's works, if you need copy one chart on one slide, change size and position of chart and then repeat action for next slides

```
Sub Export_Worksheet()
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim SldIndex As Integer

    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True

    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    SldIndex = 1

    For Each Chrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

        Chrt.Copy
    
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
            PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
        With PPTPres.Slides(SldIndex).Shapes("Chart 1")
            .Top = 170
            .Left = 530
            .Height = 250
            .Width = 400
        End With
        SldIndex = SldIndex + 1
        
    Next Chrt

End Sub
```

Comment: This breaks the loop and runs into "Run-time error 2147188160 (80048240) Automation Error"

Comment: you can accurately calculate the name of the diagram
 `PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
 For Each j In PPTPres.Slides(SldIndex).Shapes
         localName = j.Name
 Next`